# Why are integers becoming strings when I POST using jquery.ajax to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have spent the last hour attempting to figure this out to no avail. There are many posts on SO about jQuery and ajax(), but I haven't been able to find one that deals with my specific issue.

The basics of my code:

On the client:

```
var data = {"id": 1};
j.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "postTestingResult.php",
  data: {'data': data},
  dataType: "json",
  success: ajaxSuccess,
  error: ajaxError
});
```

On the server using PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data; //{"id": "1"}
```

Why is the integer value becoming a string? How do I prevent this? I really don't want to have to create a custom function to loop through my data object (which in reality is quite complex) to convert all the values.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try apply `JSON.stringify` on `data` variable: `data: {'data': JSON.stringify(data)}`

Comment: see my comment on the answer by @mesutozer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you need to `json_decode` the data you received. Then you will have variables in their the type you sent via Ajax.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
// $data['id'] is now int
```

`$_POST['data']` is a string as explained in other answers, but when you decode it you can inner elements get their proper types.

Comment: I've tried that. I get the following error: "PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" Just to be clear, my real data object contains a lot more that a single key/value, some of which are nested objects/arrays.

Comment: That should not be a problem as long is it is a valid JSON object on javascript side.. Not sure why you are getting a warning.. Are you sure parameter 1 of json_decode (which is $_POST['data']) is not already decoded? Can you try printting it to verify it is a string?

Comment: Hmmm. Good call. For some reason it isn't a string - it's coming through as an Array. But I'm not sure why. Shouldn't the jQuery ajax call I have make it a JSON string?

Comment: I think we missed one thing. Could you try JSON.stringify as suggested in your question's comment by @hindmost

Comment: I tried doing that too. That causes the 'id' to be escaped, creating: {\\"id\\": 1} I tried to figure that one out by setting the processData parameter of the jQuery.ajax() call to false, but that then causes it's own problem of $_POST['data'] not existing for some reason

Comment: Escape must be being done something else (addslashes on PHP side may be). I just tried this on my chrome developer console: `JSON.stringify({"id": 1});` and it returned without any escaping.

Comment: Hmmm. I just create a JSFiddle with an exact copy of my data object. Find it here (http://jsfiddle.net/2RNqR/1/). The way I got that was I took the escaped version I was getting in my console and did a find/replace to remove all the "\". The JSFiddle version is working perfectly. I'm not sure why my code is acting differently. It must be something in the JavaScript creating the first escape, though I have no idea what. The PHP probably adds the second escape when it sees the first one from the JavaScript, so my guess is fixing it in the JavaScript will fix it in the PHP too

Answer (score 6):

When parameters are sent through `$_GET` or `$_POST` , They are interpreted as ***strings***.

You *may* need to cast them appropriately to make them suit how it works for you.

Comment: Furthermore, for JSON to be valid, values also need to be surrounded by quotes, making this fact very clear.

Comment: And if you want to convert you need to typecast it $id = (int)$_POST["id"] ;

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want to do (and I said so in my question). I'm not married to sending as JSON. I just need to send the data object and ideally have it interpreted the way it's sent, without much extra work by me of course.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible.. JSON is an called an object _notation_ (which is.. an _object_ in the form of a string)

Comment: Yes, but there should be something server side that can properly decode the JSON. I can't believe that every developer who sends complex JSON objects has to write a custom function for the sole purpose of traversing the entire object just to convert values.