# Passing non-string data in a JQuery ajax POST call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

This is an issue I've already seen here and there on SO and on Google in general, but couldn't find an actual solution for my case, and couldn't figure one out on my own.

I'm sending data from a javascript application to a Node js server, to be used for a query on a database.

Call data:

```
var cDate = new Date();
var name = "get";
var method = "POST";
var data = {
        "db": "alerts",
        "params": {
            "selector":{
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "expires.year":{
                            "$gt": cDate.getFullYear()
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        "expires.year":{
                            "$eq": cDate.getFullYear()
                        },
                        "expires.month":{
                            "$gt": (cDate.getMonth()+1)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "expires.year":{
                            "$eq": cDate.getFullYear()
                        },
                        "expires.month":{
                            "$eq": (cDate.getMonth()+1)
                        },
                        "expires.day":{
                            "$gte": cDate.getDate()
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                },
    "sort":["created.year:number","created.month:number","created.day:number"]
}
    };
```

The actual call:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url:baseURL+"/"+name,
    dataType:"json",
    crossDomain:true,
    data:data,
    method:method,
    success: function(data,status,xhr){
        busyIndicator.hide();
        console.log("success, status: "+status);
        console.log("--> RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(data));
        if (callbackSuccess!="") window[callbackSuccess](data);
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,err){
        busyIndicator.hide();
        console.log("error, status: "+status);
        console.log(err);
        genericFailure("Errore nella chiamata al service: "+err);           
    }
});
```

Everything works fine (.ajax "stringifies" my JSON data on its own) except for the fact that dates are converted to strings as well, and therefore my subsequent db query fails (because the db attempts to confront a string vs a number).
I already tried sending

```
parseInt(<value I want to stay a number>)
```

but of course it doesn't work because the content is stringified later.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779402/why-are-integers-becoming-strings-when-i-post-using-jquery-ajax-to-a-php-script) I read that it is impossible to send numbers as numbers and I need to convert them on the server side, but the thing is if I make the same call through Postman

```
{
    "db": "alerts",
    "params": {
    "selector":{
        "$or": [
            {
            "expires.year":{
                "$gt": 2016
              }
            },
            {
            "expires.year":{
                "$eq": 2016
              },
            "expires.month":{
                "$gt": 2
              }
            },
            {
            "expires.year":{
                "$eq": 2016
              },
            "expires.month":{
                "$eq": 2
              },
            "expires.day":{
                "$gte": 29
              }
            }
        ]
        },
"sort":["created.year:number","created.month:number","created.day:number","created.hour:number","created.min:number"]
    }
}
```

it goes just as planned, with numbers staying numbers, so it **is** possible.

Anybody knows how to do so from my javascript POST call?

My thanks in advance.

**UPDATES**

I tried stringifying the data I send, before making the call:

```
data:JSON.stringify(data)
```

server-side I can see the data correctly if I log it like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body))
```

but If i try to make an object out of it and use it, i.e.

```
var bodyStr = JSON.stringify(request.body)
var bodyObj = JSON.parse(bodyStr)
console.log("db is " + bodyObj.db)
```

I get "can't read property 'db' of undefined".

If I try logging the data directly upon receiving the request, i.e.

```
console.log(request.body);
```

I get [object Object], and if I try parsing it without stringifying it first I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Comment: does the stringified data have values for the dates correct? were you able to watch it? and also what is the error?

Comment: @SreepathySp if I use JSON.stringify(data) the back-end is no longer able to parse the data I sent

Comment: @richmondwang Not sure what you mean by correct, I'm logging my requests on the server and the values for the dates are plain numbers (just like the ones in the Postman call), surrounded by quotation marks.

Comment: Did you try sending as a JSON.stringify(data) then in the backend parse it?

Comment: I did, I'll write it down in my question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: how are you passing the value via postman by the way?

Comment: Updated. Via Postman I'm selecting the "POST" method, setting raw / JSON for the body content, and writing in the body window the exact same object I wrote here in my question.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the JSON to parse it later? Doesn't that mean that `body` already has the JSON object? Plus, you already stringified it when sending the data, at least is should already be stringified. What does bodyStr hold?

Comment: I added some tests to my question. As facts stand, if I try logging request.body without stringifying I get [object Object] so for some reason that is not already stringified. As for why I parse back and forth I must admit I'm growing a bit desperate with tests.

Comment: *".ajax "stringifies" my JSON data on its own"* to be clear, no it doesn't. it sends post or get params if you give it an object, so if you wanted to send json, you would need to give it json and set the contentType properly.

Comment: @KevinB Oh God I set dataType instead of contentType, I'll fix this right away and try, thanks.

Comment: @Tom no, you need both. dataType is for what the server is responding with, contentType is for what you are sending to the server. If you're sending json, you need to specify the contentType. If you're sending queryparams, then you don't need to set the contentType.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I actually know what both of them do, I just swapped the definitions inside my head. What I had in mind is to give constraints for the request but not for the response (at least for now), which is why I'm saying I set one instead of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented, I'm unable to give you proper recognition since you solved it here and there in the comments.

I was able to make it work (with numbers staying numbers) by changing **two** things in my code:

1) **Stringify** the data before sending it

2) Set **contentType** to the desired value, in my case "application/json"

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url:baseURL+"/"+name,
    contentType:"json",
    crossDomain:true,
    data:data,
    method:method,
    success: function(data,status,xhr){
        busyIndicator.hide();
        console.log("success, status: "+status);
        console.log("--> RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(data));
        if (callbackSuccess!="") window[callbackSuccess](data);
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,err){
        busyIndicator.hide();
        console.log("error, status: "+status);
        console.log(err);
        genericFailure("Errore nella chiamata al service: "+err);           
    }
});
```

Server-side I could properly access the object without any extra parsing/stringifying e.g.

```
var dataBaseName = request.body.db;
```

Finally, as Kevin B pointed out, you also need to set

```
dataType: "json"
```

in the call, if you expect an object to be returned, otherwise you'll have a stringified one. This is "json" and not "application/json" as it is for contentType.